# why the index can take a long time to create on small table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, nonclustered-index

SQL Server 2019

Index was created with online = on.

Table has about 35000 rows with 7 columns with int, uniqueidentifier and datetime data types.
Table has only clustered index.

sp_whoisactive doesn't show any waits and locks during index creation process.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table(
    ID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    BeginTime datetime NOT NULL,
    EndTime datetime NULL,
    CreatePost uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    ClosePost uniqueidentifier NULL,
    OperationProtocol uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    StageType int NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_Table PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    ID ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
)

CREATE INDEX IXNC_Table ON Table(OperationProtocol, StageType) INCLUDE (BeginTime) WITH (FILLFACTOR=100, ONLINE=ON);
```

I stopped creation in ssms, but stopping took more than 5 minutes and killing session didn't help.
I guess that the problem is in databases metadata but how can I check and fix it?

P.S. Next day on a database with a low load, an index was created without any difficalties.

P.P.S Can someone suggest which way to look to find the cause of this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So you're using Enterprise Edition? How busy is the server?...what is the hardware provisioned behind it? "*sp_whoisactive doesn't show any waits and locks during index creation process*" - Does it show the index creation statement running at all?

Comment: What are the session wait stats when you run it?

Comment: Also, can you repeat this?

Comment: It is going to be difficult to give a definitive answer to your question given the number of possible variables. 

I would suggest doing some reading on index design, specifically how the UNIQUEIDENTIFIER data type may not be ideal for a clustered index column.

That being said, my gut feeling is that you do not have enough disk space for the transaction log to handle the sorting. Can you confirm available disk space, and whether you are allowing auto growth on your transaction log file?

Comment: @McA-the-dba transaction logs don’t handle sorting, data files do. Which one(s) is dependent on the SORT_IN_TEMPDB option being specified.

Comment: @SeanGallardy as I mentioned before whoisactive didn't show any waits but there was SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD in lastwaittype column of sys.sysprocesses system table.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi on a database with a minimum load, an index was created without any difficalties

Comment: It doesn't count you didn't create it on the same table in the same database. We want to know if it is repeatable on exsctly that table.